# Fast way to obtain underlying java component for controls in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, user-interface, custom-controls

I'd like to obtain a reference to underlying java components for the controls I have in my GUI so as to customize their appearance.

- I know about [findjobj](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) from *Yair Altman* which works really well:

  ```
  myLink = uicontrol('String', '<html><u>Button that looks like a link.</u></html>');
  jObj = findjobj(myLink);
  jObj.setContentAreaFilled(0);
  ```

  Unfortunately this solution is **quite slow** when there are a "lot" of controls to customize (because it has to parse the full hierarchy of objects in the figure and this for each control to customize).

  Moreover the figure must be visible (else controls are not instantiated and  java references cannot be found). Plus it must be moved of screen to avoid users to touch it while `findjobj` is running (sometimes make things crash because `findjobj` somehow relies on position of controls to find them while internally calling also `drawnow` which updates positions) ...

  On some machines, even with only a few controls to customize, it can be up to 10 seconds before to have the figure to appear (most of the time is spent in `findjobj`).
- I also know about [uicomponent](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14583-uicomponent-expands-uicontrol-to-all-java-classes) again from *Yair Altman* to directly create controls and get the handle to the underlying java component in one shot:

  ```
  [myLink, jObj] = uicomponent('Style', 'JButton', 'String', '<html><u>Button that looks like a link.</u></html>');
  jObj.setContentAreaFilled(0);
  ```

  Unfortunately here the **parent property can only be a figure** and of course my controls are placed in [gui layout](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox) containers to handle resizing and many other things nicely (and gui layout containter are not valid hg-handles for uicomponent to work)...

So was wondering if there could be any other **fast solution** to get underlying java components for controls in my GUI ? ... NB: I mainly only need to have buttons that looks like hyperlinks or animated gif (i.e. borderless buttons with htlm text/img inside).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I've built several GUIs that are based around GUI Layout Toolbox and that contain Java swing components. I typically arrange things so that the GUI Layout container (`HBox`, `VBox`, `Grid` etc) has a `uipanel` as a child, and then the `uipanel` has the Java swing component as a child.

You can typically parent a Java component to the `uipanel` in exactly the same way as parenting it to a figure (unlike a GUI Layout container), and it's no problem to parent a `uipanel` to a GUI Layout container.

So, for example, to add a button with a dropdown menu (no menu items, so it won't do anything, but just to illustrate):

```
>> u = uipanel;
>> ddbuttonclass = 'com.mathworks.widgets.DropdownButton';
>> ddbutton = javaObjectEDT(ddbuttonclass);
>> [jddbutton, hjddbutton] = javacomponent(ddbutton, [30,30, 60, 30], u);
```

Now you can parent `u` to a GUI Layout container, and you get all the nice resizing.

I'm not that familiar with Yair's `uicomponent`, but if you can get the handle of the java component somehow, you should be able to use something like the above.

PS If you want his direct input, @Yair is sometimes active on SO - he may get notified if I mention his name. If you're doing a lot of Java/MATLAB GUI work, I'd also recommend buying his [book](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/books/matlab-java).

Comment: I yet don't see how to have the `javacomponent` to automatically resize as its wrapper `uipanel` does within the `uiextras.grid`(see my [test code](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/0dccb5d8b7bbf389bbe8)) but this looks like great direction to go. I need to have a deeper look on that point prior to validate your answer but will let you know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Referring to your test code: return a second output argument from `javacomponent`, i.e. do `[jBtn, hjBtn] = javacomponent(...`. This extra output argument gives the handle wrapper to `jBtn`. Then `set(hjBtn, 'Units', 'normalized')`. With this, I get the resize behaviour I think you're hoping for.

Comment: Thanks both of you. It works like a charm. I definitely need to buy @yair 's book now.

Answer (score 1):

UICOMPONENT was designed to be a direct replacement of both Matlab's built-in UICONTROL and JAVACOMPONENT functions. This means that you can directly place a UICOMPONENT within panels, even those created by the GUI Layout toolbox.

You might need to cast the layout panel's handle to double (`double(hPanel)`) on some Matlab releases but that's about it:

```
[myLink, jObj] = uicomponent('Parent',hPanel, ...);
[myLink, jObj] = uicomponent('Parent',double(hPanel), ...);  % on some Matlab releases
```

You could also use JAVACOMPONENT directly, but it doesn't really give you any benefits over UICOMPONENT, since UICOMPONENT uses JAVACOMPONENT under the hood and also adds important functionality (such as ensuring the component is placed on the EDT, and merging important properties from the Matlab wrapper).

As for FINDJOBJ, you can speed it up a bit by specifying the target object class using the `'class'` parameter. But if your figure contains hundreds of controls it might still be slow. To this day, close to 10 years after my first version of FINDJOBJ, I still do not know of a direct way to get the underlying Java object. I assume there is one that is used internally by MathWorks, but I do not know it.

As @SamRoberts mentioned, this is all discussed in my book...